# Disposable platform instances

Tags: linux, macos, window, cloud, virtual-machine

Let's say I'm building an open source software on GitHub.
And I have issues being reported by users. And when I ask them their platform, various platforms are being reported.

For example, one bug is specific to OS X 10 El Capitan
There's another one that manifests in plain GNU Linux
A lot of it is on Window 7 and Windows 10

As a developer I run only one operating system. How can I temporarily
"spin up" major platforms, to troubleshoot an issue?

Comment: if i create an open source project to cater to this need, will i be able to find a sponsor for bandwidth, disk and the cpu power?